# R low performance when writing to SQLite

Tags: r, sqlite, gdal, rgdal

I observe a very low performance when writing spatial data to "SQLite" via writeOGR() in R. In the code below writing 10.000 testpoints takes approx.2 minutes, but 0.3sec when using "ESRI Shapefile".

Is this an expected behavior of the R-function and are there options to speed this up? Thanks for any help.

System: Ubuntu 15.04, R 3.2.2

```
    ###running Example
    library(foreign)
    library(rgdal)

    #Testdata
    count<-10000 #define size
    d.data<-data.frame(meter_x=runif(count,2490000,2825000), 
    meter_y=runif(count,1090000,1295000), col1=runif(count,1,100000))

    #create spatial points
    coordinates(d.data)<- ~ meter_x + meter_y  
    proj4string(d.data)=CRS("+init=epsg:2056")

    #compare shapefile to sqlite
    #NOTE:'overwrite_layer=TRUE' gets ignored for SQLite and needs manual delete
    unlink("./test.sqlite")
    system.time(writeOGR(d.data, dsn="./test.sqlite",layer="test",driver= "SQLite",overwrite_layer=TRUE)) #test SQLITE
    system.time(writeOGR(d.data, dsn=".",layer="test",driver = "ESRI Shapefile",overwrite_layer=TRUE)) #test Shapefile
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I'm observing this behavior as well (even count = 100 takes more than one second). Is it faster if you export to shapefile first and then use `ogr2ogr` or a similar method to import the shapefile to a SQLite database? The following might be related: https://hub.qgis.org/issues/7822

Comment: By default SQLite use very *light* parameters (like `cache_size=2000` *(its in kb)*) and the `synchronous` mode is ON for example. When i use `ogr2ogr` to write on a SQLite db i generally use parameters like these : `-gt 65536` `--config OGR_SQLITE_SYNCHRONOUS OFF` `--config OGR_SQLITE_CACHE 2048` (its in MB). I know the `writeOGR` function can take a `layer_option` and/or a `dataset_option` argument but I can't find the way to use them properly in order to tune up the performance of SQLite table writing.

Comment: @krlmr: The bug posted by does not seem to be relevant for gdal 1.11 any more. Following the example of [qgis-issues](hub.qgis.org/issues/7822) my system needs 0m16.129s to convert. @ mgc: This is a very helpful extension. It reduced processing time of the above example to 0m3.418s.